# how to shorten a string by certain number of characters?

Tags: php

Is there a php function that can chop let's say 10 chars of the end of a string without calling strlen ? So I can avoid unnecessary repeating of variable names.

all I know is `substr($str,0,strlen($str)-10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: You should also check to subtract length of the `$str` if the length is less that your required chars to remove.

```
substr($str,0,-10);
```

Comment: The character limit is there to encourage you to write a meaningful explanation of your answer, not to fill it with meaningless padding.

Answer (score 7):

Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php.

> ...
>
> If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will
>   be omitted from the end of string.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> $rest = substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
> ```

Comment: To be explicit: `substr( $str, 0, -10 );` is all that's necessary.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to comment?  I don't see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation for `substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) clearly states:

> ```
> string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
> ```
>
> If length is given and is negative, then that many characters will be
>   omitted from the end of string (after the start position has been
>   calculated when a start is negative). If start denotes the position of
>   this truncation or beyond, false will be returned.

So:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, -10);
```

Please, always use the documentation as your first port of call for reference questions. There is no reason at all not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you give it a negative length, it'll remove that many characters from the end.

```
substr($str, 0, -10);
```

Comment: You were first. As to the question, yep, my bad. At least you folks got some points.

Comment: @rsk82: he wasn't first. first was Oli

Comment: Yes, sorry, so I will accept the guy who has least points since you all are right.

Answer (score 0):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/4fb74.php

-10 without strlen :)

```
<?php 
$str = "01234567890123456789"; 
echo substr($str,0,-10);
```

outputs 0123456789

Comment: Before you edited, your first shot at an answer was a link and "-10 :)" which is not what I would consider a useful response.  I've removed the downvote.

Comment: @SeanBright: ah, yes I was trying to be the fastest. Sorry for that